# JSON schema - display values on drop down based on another drop down

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema, jsoneditor

I've defined [JSON Schema](https://pmk65.github.io/jedemov2/dist/demo.html?schema=EQbwOgdgBFbATgUwI4FcCWSAmcBcUBtSGGOAI3gEMIsBnOAGmJLi0QDd0BjRe4ZgLpNocAA7wA9qMTwALul54o4aLGAVqdJSpbAAJEgBmSuAGIA9G0PoI6eRIi1zGmn2YBfYu%2BFqrNu%2BgOfLg6pOpUrtrMuvKyADaIJsAAQhFawD4karIAntJJtLLwNgDmjNFhiBCoALZKRKpZagCCoqIJ5Y1ZcADiEhIlHRkVugAiiHFxcCNQQiOsiIaUqHGySa3tifyN3sxwlJMA%2BmycPMHK88C5%2BcD4cIXFEGXDXWpVtfUzagAylKKyUk6TTCABVKGQEmsXsC1AAFAAWDi2MwE0V2jQWRxO3EUtwurzg1y2d2AD1KQO6wHedTxDRhcF%2B%2F0B0OBcDBEMQUJRFU80HRanQxjxoTEkmkcgU51Cahc6Xw0rCXCCUKgJPGk2mO0yaiQaEwiBwtJmC1OuIqqNU%2FOy8KqUQxwHEUhk8lx8oqJpxUuN%2BiMSQsfls9kclgmcWOHE9mqavJIVp1KAw2E%2Br18EbOUZIFpgVrgE1oxOloqdEtd%2BMp2PTwu9BkWfpD1kDgWDBzDFbNrxj2e1cF1iYNydZwDbbi6WagMd57mAQA&value=ETI%3D&code=EQehAIBUAsFNwGYHsA2KkHcCWA7A5uCrrAM7gCGATvALbk4Am5ALkpQJ4WPjXkNI4U7AHTgAmkgCu4AMb0KDBrMklWNWUgbxyAIyQA3bdx2x0GYQB0cWBOAAUAKxKwGWVpXC5V9GbCS3sRkxhACkAZQB5ADkAUVd3AEpwJxc3NmEtVUokdjsEgG4rFPi2cABecBxYDHBA%2FnNw6Li0yjt%2BGUkaWBxmYQBHSVgOMNNYGXc7C2AAYicBAFpU93nkShophIAaZJcWcgLgIA%3D&style=ETI%3D&theme=bootstrap3&iconlib=bootstrap3&object_layout=normal&template=default&show_errors=interaction&required_by_default=0&no_additional_properties=0&display_required_only=0&remove_empty_properties=0&keep_oneof_values=1&ajax=0&ajaxCredentials=0&show_opt_in=0&disable_edit_json=0&disable_collapse=0&disable_properties=0&disable_array_add=0&disable_array_reorder=0&disable_array_delete=0&enable_array_copy=0&array_controls_top=0&disable_array_delete_all_rows=0&disable_array_delete_last_row=0&prompt_before_delete=1&lib_aceeditor=0&lib_autocomplete=0&lib_sceditor=0&lib_simplemde=0&lib_select2=0&lib_selectize=0&lib_choices=0&lib_flatpickr=0&lib_signaturepad=0&lib_mathjs=0&lib_cleavejs=0&lib_jodit=0&lib_jquery=0&lib_dompurify=0) and I'm using [JSON Editor](https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor) to render a form having two drop-down list (Brands and Devices) and the expected form looks like this:

[image]

**Brands** drop down list consists of 3 values:

- Apple
- Google
- Dell

Similarly, **Devices** drop down list also consists of 3 values:

- Laptop
- Tablet
- Phone

However, there is a condition to render the values on ***Devices*** drop down list and the conditions are as follows:

1. If **Device** is **Dell** then just show *Laptop* and *Tablet* as devices
2. Else show all of the available devices

I've used **If then** and **else** of JSON schema draft 7 to achieve the expected result and my solution so far is shown below ([Here's](https://pmk65.github.io/jedemov2/dist/demo.html?schema=EQbwOgdgBFbATgUwI4FcCWSAmcBcUBtSGGOAI3gEMIsBnOAGmJLi0QDd0BjRe4ZgLpNocAA7wA9qMTwALul54o4aLGAVqdJSpbAAJEgBmSuAGIA9G0PoI6eRIi1zGmn2YBfYu%2BFqrNu%2BgOfLg6pOpUrtrMuvKyADaIJsAAQhFawD4karIAntJJtLLwNgDmjNFhiBCoALZKRKpZagCCoqIJ5Y1ZcADiEhIlHRkVugAiiHFxcCNQQiOsiIaUqHGySa3tifyN3sxwlJMA%2BmycPMHK88C5%2BcD4cIXFEGXDXWpVtfUzagAylKKyUk6TTCABVKGQEmsXsC1AAFAAWDi2MwE0V2jQWRxO3EUtwurzg1y2d2AD1KQO6wHedTxDRhcF%2B%2F0B0OBcDBEMQUJRFU80HRanQxjxoTEkmkcgU51Cahc6Xw0rCXCCUKgJPGk2mO0yaiQaEwiBwtJmC1OuIqqNU%2FOy8KqUQxwHEUhk8lx8oqJpxUuN%2BiMSQsfls9kclgmcWOHE9mqavJIVp1KAw2E%2Br18EbOUZIFpgVrgE1oxOloqdEtd%2BMp2PTwu9BkWfpD1kDgWDBzDFbNrxj2e1cF1iYNydZwDbbi6WagMd57mAQA&value=ETI%3D&code=EQehAIBUAsFNwGYHsA2KkHcCWA7A5uCrrAM7gCGATvALbk4Am5ALkpQJ4WPjXkNI4U7AHTgAmkgCu4AMb0KDBrMklWNWUgbxyAIyQA3bdx2x0GYQB0cWBOAAUAKxKwGWVpXC5V9GbCS3sRkxhACkAZQB5ADkAUVd3AEpwJxc3NmEtVUokdjsEgG4rFPi2cABecBxYDHBA%2FnNw6Li0yjt%2BGUkaWBxmYQBHSVgOMNNYGXc7C2AAYicBAFpU93nkShophIAaZJcWcgLgIA%3D&style=ETI%3D&theme=bootstrap3&iconlib=bootstrap3&object_layout=normal&template=default&show_errors=interaction&required_by_default=0&no_additional_properties=0&display_required_only=0&remove_empty_properties=0&keep_oneof_values=1&ajax=0&ajaxCredentials=0&show_opt_in=0&disable_edit_json=0&disable_collapse=0&disable_properties=0&disable_array_add=0&disable_array_reorder=0&disable_array_delete=0&enable_array_copy=0&array_controls_top=0&disable_array_delete_all_rows=0&disable_array_delete_last_row=0&prompt_before_delete=1&lib_aceeditor=0&lib_autocomplete=0&lib_sceditor=0&lib_simplemde=0&lib_select2=0&lib_selectize=0&lib_choices=0&lib_flatpickr=0&lib_signaturepad=0&lib_mathjs=0&lib_cleavejs=0&lib_jodit=0&lib_jquery=0&lib_dompurify=0) a link to interactive JSON Schema playground):

```
{
  "required": [
    "brands",
    "devices"
  ],
 "properties": {
  "brands": {
   "$ref": "#/definitions/brands"
  }
 },
 "definitions":{
   "brands": {
     "title": "Brands",
     "type": "string",
     "enum": [
       "Apple",
       "Google",
       "Dell"
      ],
     "default": "Apple"
   },
  "all_devices": {
     "type": "string",
     "enum": [
       "Laptop",
       "Tablet",
       "Phone"
      ]
   },
   "dell_devices": {
     "type": "string",
     "enum": [
       "Laptop",
       "Tablet"
      ]
    }
 },
 "if": {
  "properties": {
   "brands": {
     "const" : "Dell"
   },
   "required": [
      "devices"
    ]
  },
  "then": {
   "properties": {
    "devices": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/dell_devices"
     }
   },
   "required": [
      "devices"
    ]
  },
  "else":{
   "properties": {
    "devices": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/all_devices"
     }
   },
   "required": [
      "devices"
    ]
  }
 }
}
```

However, the second drop down (**Devices**) is not not displaying at all and I'm not sure how I can debug the issue as I'm new to JSON schema.

I would really apprecriate if anyone could guide me to the right direction or maybe suggest any other approaches to achieve the result that I desired.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `JSON Editor` only supports draft 3 and 4 of JSON Schema. `if`/`then`/`else` blocks were introduced in later versions, which don't appear to be supported. https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor/issues/359

Comment: Thank @Relequestual for pointing that out.